# What's the difference between "onwheel" and "onscroll" events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

When I tried to change the default scroll bar property, I found that it's not convenient by rewriting callback function for `scroll()` or `onscroll` events, instead, I should rewrite a callback function for "onwheel" events.

So what's the difference between `onwheel` and `onscroll` anyways? I imagine that default `onwheel` handler by browsers would automatically trigger `onscroll` function to move the scroll bar, which is why `preventDefault` in `onwheel`'s callback will prevent scroll bar moving. Am I right? Who has a better and more specific explanation?

Comment: `onwheel`? I've never seen that before o.O

Comment: [MDN about `onwheel`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/onwheel) _"**Non-standard**
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."_

Comment: onwheel is not standard and not all browsers inplement it. It does not catch scrolling via arrows, spacebar, etc.

Comment: Just 'wheel' is the standard implementation it seems. The difference is that wheel triggers when the wheel on a mouse or other input device is used. And scroll triggers anytime you scroll, be it whith a wheel or by clicking the scroll arrows or using the scroll hand or whatever.

Comment: CMIW Looks like Cerberus comment no longer applies. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#handler-onwheel

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`onwheel` *specifically* fires when the mouse wheel is spun. `onscroll` fires for any kind of scrolling, including keyboard buttons like the arrow keys, Home, End, Page Up, Page Down, space bar, tabbing etc.

Note that `onwheel` is non-standard and should be avoided unless you're specifically targeting browsers that support it and/or are providing an extra feature whose absence won't be felt.

Comment: Why the page will scroll when wheel or onwheel fires and won't scroll as default if wheel or onwheel is prevented? Does it mean that scroll if triggered inside the default behavior of wheel?

Comment: Yes. It's the same reason that clicking a link and calling `preventDefault()` prevents navigation. The default behaviour of `onwheel` is to scroll the page.

Comment: Note that `onwheel` _is_ part of the standard, though.

Answer (score 5):

`onwheel`: Occurs when the mouse wheel is rolled up or down over an element.

`onscroll` Occurs when an element's scrollbar is being scrolled.

It's important to note that in Internet Explorer, the wheel event is only supported through `addEventListener`. You can't use the `onwheel` event attribute.

onwheel doesn't work in Safari or in IE8 or earlier.

Comment: `onwheel` works in Safari since version 7

Answer (score 3):

The `onwheel` event triggers on scroll AND on zoom, as you move the mouse wheel, while the `onscroll` event only occurs when an element's scrollbar is being scrolled (i believe that includes touch scrolling as well).

Answer (score 1):

[MDN about `onwheel`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/onwheel)

> ***Non-standard**
>
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.*

The `onwheel` event gets fired when the mouse wheel is scrolled. This physical action may or may not also result in scroll events.

Basically, `onscroll` is what you need.