# react-use-gesture useScroll not detecting scroll event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I am trying to use the react-use-gesture library, but can't even seem to get some simple hooks working. I'm trying to use the useScroll hook (eventually to get an animation running with react-spring), but when I bind it to my  component, nothing happens.

```
import { useScroll} from 'react-use-gesture';

function App() {
    const bind = useScroll((e) => {
        e.scrolling ? console.log("I'm being scrolled") : console.log("I'm not being scrolled");

    });
    return (
        <div className="App" {...bind()}>
            // All of my other components in App
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly enough, I wasn't able to get the `useScroll` hook to work either, but the `useWheel` hook works just fine.

```
import React from "react";
import { useWheel } from "react-use-gesture";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const wheel = useWheel(state => {
    console.log("wheeling", state.wheeling);
  });
  return (
    <div className="App" {...wheel()}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit vibrant-night-mrb6f]

Was curious as to why scroll events weren't getting picked up but the mouse events were. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719495/whats-the-difference-between-onwheel-and-onscroll-events) sheds a bit of light on the matter.

**EDIT**

Was able to get the scrolling working by passing optional config object, in this case, setting the DOM target to `window`. According to [Options explained](https://use-gesture.netlify.com/docs/options#options-explained) it is recommended to use an effect hook versus spreading in as a prop (*though it worked in the codesandbox spread in*).

```
export default function App() {
  const scroll = useScroll(state => {
    console.log("scrolling", state.scrolling);
  }, {
    domTarget: window,
  });

  useEffect(scroll, [scroll]);

  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `overflow` property to `scroll` in your container's style, otherwise no scroll event beside window's will be trigger.

```
import { useScroll } from 'react-use-gesture';

function App() {
    const bind = useScroll((e) => {
        e.scrolling ? console.log("I'm being scrolled") : console.log("I'm not being scrolled");

    });
    return (
        <div className="App" style={{overflow: 'scroll'}} {...bind()}>
            // All of my other components in App
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```