# Scroll direction of the WheelEvent delta*

Tags: javascript, mousewheel

The [MDN wheel event docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) it is specifies the following:

> Even when it does, the delta* values in the wheel event don't necessarily reflect the content's scrolling direction.

Anyone know under which condition the delta value might not reflect the scrolling direction ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719495/whats-the-difference-between-onwheel-and-onscroll-events
Seems the difference is that you can use wheel even if there was nothing to scroll, and scroll explicitly means something was scrolled. I guess you can think of it like "onClick of the wheel" (ie content scrolls horizontally and you used wheel in a vertical way)